# Spring boot Current request is not a multipart request when deploy to server

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload, vuejs3, multipartform-data

I run BE in localhost it worked but when deploy to server, it's not worked.
Here is my API code:

```java
    @Validated
    @PostMapping(value = "/account-info/import", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<?> importExcel(
            HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
            @ValidExcelFile @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file
    ) throws IOException {
        // something
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
```

Here is `@ValidExcelFile` annotation:

```java
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {FileValidator.class})
public @interface ValidExcelFile {
    String message() default "Only excel file are allowed";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

class FileValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidExcelFile, MultipartFile> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidExcelFile constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(MultipartFile multipartFile, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        boolean result = true;

        String contentType = multipartFile.getContentType();
        if (!isSupportedContentType(contentType)) {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private boolean isSupportedContentType(String contentType) {
        return contentType.equals("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    }
}
```

Here is my Vue3:

```js
          <form class="form row" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row fv-row mb-5">
              <el-upload
                ref="uploadRef"
                class="upload-demo"
                action="http://localhost:8081/api/account-info/import"
                accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
                drag
                :limit="1"
                :headers="{ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;' }"
                :on-exceed="handleExceed"
                :http-request="handleRequest"
              >
              </el-upload>
            </div>
          </form>
```

I set the action is `localhost` then it worked, but if I change to server IP, it got error with status 400: `Current request is not a multipart request`.
This is request info: [request info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jquqD.png)

Please help me fix this. Thanks!